# Text editor with paging similar to ms word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html 5 jquery or java script
Is it possible to implement paging similar to MS Word in a rich text editor using JavaScript.

I need to implement an editor using JavaScript that contains text in pages. If i type text that exceeds the ficed limit of a page then automatically a new page is created and text overflows to the new page with formatting intact. Also if I copy large text from another source then it should calculate the number of pages depending on the text length and divide it into pages with all the formatting of the original text.

I need to break the text into lines based on pixel size using only JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

If i delete contents from inside a page then contents from the next page should be populated in the current page and if all the contents from a page is deleted then the page should be deleted. Almost every paging feature in MS word should be implemented in this one.

Comment: Hey @Mujtaba Hyder, and welcome to Stackoverflow!
You asked, so **yes, it is possible.** I will work on it for you.

Answer (score 0):

## Notes

This uses javascript without jQuery, CSS and HTML5. Each page is a `div` with a class of `page` and is inside the `main` element.

## Code snippet:

```js
var main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
var mainChildren = main.children;
var limit = innerWidth * 2;

setInterval(() => {
  if (!main.children) {
    main.appendChild(document.createElement("div").classList.add("page"));
  }
  for (var i2 = 0; i2 < mainChildren.length; i2++) {
    var divChildren = mainChildren[i2].children;
    var height = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < divChildren.length; i++) {
      height += divChildren[i].offsetHeight;
      //console.log(height);
      if (height >= limit) {
        if (!mainChildren[i2 + 1]) {
          var n = document.createElement("div");
          n.classList.add("page");
          main.appendChild(n);
        }

        mainChildren[i2 + 1].prepend(divChildren[i]);
        divChildren[i].remove();
      }
    }
  }
}, 100);

function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html, selectPastedContent) {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();

      // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
      // only relatively recently standardized and is not supported in
      // some browsers (IE9, for one)
      var el = document.createElement("div");
      el.innerHTML = html;
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        node, lastNode;
      while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
        lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
      }
      var firstNode = frag.firstChild;
      range.insertNode(frag);

      // Preserve the selection
      if (lastNode) {
        range = range.cloneRange();
        range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
        if (selectPastedContent) {
          range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
        } else {
          range.collapse(true);
        }
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
  } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
    // IE < 9
    var originalRange = sel.createRange();
    originalRange.collapse(true);
    sel.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    if (selectPastedContent) {
      range = sel.createRange();
      range.setEndPoint("StartToStart", originalRange);
      range.select();
    }
  }
}
var keymap = {
  49: {
    t: "h1",
    x: "Heading level 1"
  },
  50: {
    t: "h2",
    x: "Heading level 2"
  },
  51: {
    t: "h3",
    x: "Heading level 3"
  },
  52: {
    t: "h4",
    x: "Heading level 4"
  },
  53: {
    t: "h5",
    x: "Heading level 5"
  },
  54: {
    t: "h6",
    x: "Heading level 6"
  },
  78: {
    t: "div",
    x: "Normal text"
  },
  73: {
    t: "i",
    x: "italics",
    i: true
  },
  66: {
    t: "b",
    x: "bold text",
    i: true
  },
  85: {
    t: "u",
    x: "underlined text",
    i: true
  }
};
onkeydown = function(e) {
  var e = e || window.event; // for IE to cover IEs window event-object
  console.log(e);
  if (e.altKey && keymap[e.keyCode]) {
    //mainChildren[mainChildren.length - 1].appendChild()
    pasteHtmlAtCaret("<" + keymap[e.keyCode].t + ">" + keymap[e.keyCode].x + "</" + keymap[e.keyCode].t + ">");
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(node);

    //if(keymap[e.keyCode].t.match(/^h\d$/)){
    node.innerText = "Continue typing...";
    //}else{
    // node.innerText = "\u00A0";
    //}


    var node2 = keymap[e.keyCode].i ? document.createElement("span") : document.createElement("div");
    node2.innerHTML = node.innerHTML;

    getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.parentElement.appendChild(node2);
    node.remove();
    //getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endContainer.textContent = "";
    return false;
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.15s all;
}
.page {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 7px white;
}
p {
  padding: 1em 0;
}
main,
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<main contenteditable="true">
  <div class="page">
    <div>Start typing here!</div>
    <div>Use alt+1 for biggest heading, alt+2 for bigger heading, alt+3 for big heading, etc. Use alt+b for bold, alt+i for italics, and alt+u for underline.</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image: Edit on Codepen]